# Keras - Interference in models

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am developing something in Django and have two models in two different views. One model has nothing to do with another, but both are called one after another.

**Model 1:**

```
    classificador = Sequential()
    classificador.add(Dense(units=60, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="random_uniform", input_shape=(38,)))
    classificador.add(Dense(units=60, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="random_uniform"))
    classificador.add(Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"))
    classificador.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["binary_accuracy"])
    classificador.fit(X_Treino, Y_Treino, batch_size=10, epochs=100)
```

**Model 2**

```
    classificador_outlier = Sequential()
    classificador_outlier.add(Dense(units=45, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="random_uniform", input_shape=(6,)))
    classificador_outlier.add(Dense(units=45, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="random_uniform"))
    classificador_outlier.add(Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"))
    classificador_outlier.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["binary_accuracy"])
    classificador_outlier.fit(X_Treino_Outlier, Y_Treino_Outlier, batch_size=10, epochs=100)
```

I think one model is interfering in another. If I run just one model (anyone), it works well. When running both, I receive the following message running `Model 1` (last one to run):

> Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [10,38], In[1]: [6,45]

Observe that the input of `Model 1` has (10, 38) shape, and message error is referecing values that are related to  `Model 2`.

What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

It worked after clearing session, as sugested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45063602/attempting-to-reset-tensorflow-graph-when-using-keras-failing)

```
from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
```